# Recursive JavaScript function to locate an object by its UID

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm having an issue returning the element which has been found in this hierarchical tree.
For example, if my selected item is:

```
{
 "UID": 49,
 "GUID": "",
 "LocationName": "Doctor Smith's Office",

 "LocationType": {
    "UID": 2,
    "LocationTypeName": "Practice",
    "Description": "other location"
 }
}
```

I will match up the `UID` to the below array of objects.

```js
{
  UID: 2,
  GUID: "",
  LocationName: "USA",
  ParentLocation: null,
  subs: [{
 UID: 42,
 GUID: "",
 LocationName: "New Jersey",
 Description: "",
 subs: [{
  UID: 3,
  GUID: "",
  LocationName: "Essex County",
  ParentLocation: null,
  "subs":[
   UID: 4,
   LocationName: "Newark",
   ParentLocation: 3,
   "subs": [
    {
     "UID": 49,
     "GUID": "",
     "LocationName": "Doctor Smith's Office",
             
     "LocationType": {
      "UID": 2,
      "LocationTypeName": "Practice",
      "Description": "other location"
     },                                    
     "subs": [
      {
       "HostID": 38,
       "HostName": "Ocean Host",
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  ]
   }                  
 ]
  }]
};
```

```js
let foundItem = this.findInTreeView(this.treeviewData[0], node.selectedNode);

// find selected node in treeview nav
 // param: data - the treeview dataset
 // param: selected - the selected node to be searched for in param 'data'
 findInTreeView(data: any, selected: any ) {  
  let found;
  if (this.foundInTree(data, selected)) {   
   return data;
  }
  let elem;
  let ary = data.subs;
  for (var i=0; i < ary.length; i++) {
   elem = ary[i];
   if (this.foundInTree(elem, selected)) {  
                // *** PROBLEM: If func has return true, I want to return the 'elem' object. 
    return elem;
   }
  }
  for (var i=0; i < ary.length; i++) {
   elem = ary[i];
   if (elem.subs !== undefined) { 
    // recurse subs array
    let found = this.findInTreeView(elem, selected); 
    if (found) {
     return elem;
    }
   }
  } 
  //return elem;  
 }
  
  foundInTree(treeItem, node) {
  if (treeItem.UID === node.UID) {
   return true;   
  }
  else {
   return false;
  }
 }
```

Comment: What's your expected output?  The whole object including `subs`?  The object without `subs`?  The path to the object?  A boolean to say if it's there?'

Comment: I would like the object `elem` to be returned. For instance, ` this.findInTreeView(elem, selected);` says that my user `selected` value should match the array `elem` passed into the function.

Comment: I don't think that actually answers my question.  If you want to return the `elem` supplied, just return it.  Are you looking only to match on UID?  

So the input could be an object with a `UID` property, and the output would be the whole object  that matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be far easier to use a recursive `reduce` function, like this:

```js
const input={UID:2,GUID:"",LocationName:"USA",ParentLocation:null,subs:[{UID:42,GUID:"",LocationName:"New Jersey",Description:"",subs:[{UID:3,GUID:"",LocationName:"Essex County",ParentLocation:null,"subs":[{UID:4,LocationName:"Newark",ParentLocation:3,"subs":[{"UID":49,"GUID":"","LocationName":"Doctor Smith's Office","LocationType":{"UID":2,"LocationTypeName":"Practice","Description":"other location"},"subs":[{"HostID":38,"HostName":"Ocean Host",}]}]}]}]}]};

const findUIDObj = (uid, parent) => {
  const { UID, subs } = parent;
  if (UID === uid) {
    const { subs, ...rest } = parent;
    return rest;
  }
  if (subs) return subs.reduce((found, child) => found || findUIDObj(uid, child), null);
};
console.log(findUIDObj(49, input))
```

Comment: and  you're using the spread operator here, correct ? --> `const { subs, ...rest } = parent;`

Comment: Yes, that separates out the `subs` property from the rest of the object, so as to return the object minus the `subs` property.

Comment: that's just awesome. I didn't realize the power and usefulness of the `reduce` function for my scenario.

Comment: it would also be nice to know how it could have worked in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an explicit function which searches for the wanted `UID`.

```js
function find(array, UID) {
    var object;
    array.some(o => {
        if (o.UID === UID) {
            return object = o;
        }
        return object = find(o.subs, UID);
    });
    return object;
}

var object = { UID: 2, GUID: "", LocationName: "USA", ParentLocation: null, subs: [{ UID: 42, GUID: "", LocationName: "New Jersey", Description: "", subs: [{ UID: 3, GUID: "", LocationName: "Essex County", ParentLocation: null, subs: [{ UID: 4, LocationName: "Newark", ParentLocation: 3, subs: [{ UID: 49, GUID: "", LocationName: "Doctor Smith's Office", LocationType: { UID: 2, LocationTypeName: "Practice", Description: "other location" }, subs: [{ HostID: 38, HostName: "Ocean Host", }] }] }] }] }] };

console.log(find([object], 49));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to write a fairly generic version of a tree-finding function, and then configure it for your specific problem.  Here we choose to test by matching on a supplied UID, we descend into children by looking at the `subs` property, and we convert the result by stripping out the `subs` property:

```js
const searchTreeDF = (kids, test, convert, node) => test(node) // depth-first search
  ? convert(node) 
  : (kids(node) || []).reduce(
      (found, child) => found || searchTreeDF(kids, test, convert, child), 
      false
  )

const subs = node => node.subs
const matchId = (uid) => (item) => item.UID === uid
const convert = ({subs, ...rest}) => ({...rest})

const findUid = (uid, tree) => searchTreeDF(subs, matchId(uid), convert, tree)
// ...
const tree = {"GUID": "", "LocationName": "USA", "ParentLocation": null, "UID": 2, "subs": [{"Description": "", "GUID": "", "LocationName": "New Jersey", "UID": 42, "subs": [{"GUID": "", "LocationName": "Essex County", "ParentLocation": null, "UID": 3, "subs": [{"LocationName": "Newark", "ParentLocation": 3, "UID": 4, "subs": [{"GUID": "", "LocationName": "Doctor Smith's Office", "LocationType": {"Description": "other location", "LocationTypeName": "Practice", "UID": 2}, "UID": 49, "subs": [{"HostID": 38, "HostName": "Ocean Host"}]}]}]}]}]}


console.log(findUid(49, tree))
```

But if we didn't want to pass in the `UID` directly, but instead wanted to pass in an element that has its own `UID` property, we could write

```
const matchElem = (elem) => (item) => elem.UID === item.UID
```

and then do this:

```
const findUid2 = (elem, tree) => searchTreeDF(subs, matchElem(elem), convert, tree)
// ...
findUid2({UID: 49}, tree)
```

Or if we wanted to not convert the result, and keep the `subs` property, we could just supply an identity function for `convert`:

```
const findUid = (uid, tree) => searchTreeDF(subs, matchId(uid), x => x, tree)
```

Or we could mix and match as we please.  Also note that the configuration does not have to use named functions.  We could just as easily write

```
const findUid = (uid, tree) => searchTreeDF(
  node => node.subs || [], 
  (item) => item.UID === uid,
  ({subs, ...rest}) => ({...rest}), 
  tree
)
```

Generic functions are not always the right answer.  But they can help separate out those things that change from the more basic algorithm we're writing.  I think in this case it helps make things more maintainable.